# Tesseract hOCR iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tesseract, hocr

I am learning how to use the Tesseract API and I am interested in the hOCR output function. Currently I am using this code to scan the image.

```
 Tesseract* tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
tesseract.delegate = self;
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@.-():" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0" forKey:@"tessedit_create_hocr"];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card.jpg"];

CGFloat newWidth = 1200;
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newWidth);
image = [image resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];


[tesseract setImage:image]; //image to check
[tesseract recognize];

 NSLog(@"Here is the text %@", [tesseract recognizedText]);
```

Everything is compiling fine, but I want to know how to store the .html that is returned by the hOCR function.
Can I store it inside of a variable? I need to be able to access this file in my program after it has been generated. Any insight on how to use hOCR on iOS is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an NSString if you proceed as follows.

```
- (NSString *)getHOCRText {
        char *boxtext = _tesseract->GetHOCRText(0);
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:boxtext];
}
```

Later you can convert this NSString to NSData.

```
    NSData *xmlData = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

So that you can parse this data using NSXMLParser

```
        NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
```

Hope you are aware remaining parsing procedures.

Comment: Does hOCR return a string of XML? Or is it HTML?

Comment: Its HTML but While you call the method getHOCRText mentioned above you will get a NSString which can be converted to NSData and can parse using NSXMLParser. If you NSLog that NSString you can see its similar to xml. So you can treat it as xml response and can parse it using NSXMLParser.

Comment: From the HTML I need the text blocks on the card, will I be able to get the blocks from the HTML by parsing? I am new to Tesseract and parsing. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248883/Objective-C-Fundamentals-NSXMLParser. There are lot of tutorials for this. Just make a search.